# convert currency according to daily rates magento

Tags: magento, converters, currency, automatic-updates

Hi i have **multisite** in **magento**. In this i want the

> price of the product
>
> should be adjusted according to daily dollar rate

.

> Like if today the price of 1 dollar is rs 20
>
> and my product price for Indian store view is equal to 1 $ but it
>   will visible as rs20
>
> but when the dollar rate will be increased or decreased i want the
>   price of my product for Indian store view should adjust automatically.

Can anyone suggest me any idea how can i achieve this .

thanks in advance.

Comment: In magento admin panel where we have the option configuration->manage currency and you can define the value of 1 $ and it automatically reflected on website. But you have to do it manually because there is no API through which you can identify current dollar rate

Answer (score 1):

Go to app\code\core\Mage\Directory\etc\config.xml

You can find

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <currency_rates_update>
            <run>
                <model>directory/observer::scheduledUpdateCurrencyRates</model>
            </run>
        </currency_rates_update>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Replace it with

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <currency_rates_update>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>00 01,13 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>directory/observer::scheduledUpdateCurrencyRates</model>
            </run>
        </currency_rates_update>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

So that currency updates will run twice a day

Then change the version of config.xml

```
<Mage_Directory>
        <version>1.6.0.X</version>
</Mage_Directory>
```

X to one version incremented

Then configure cron.php on root folder to run once in an hour or once in 5 hours so that it schedules currency updates row on table cron_schedule. for test purpose run it twice a minute and verify.

Answer (score 0):

Magento have it own currency convert but it  will be update using cron service.
Some other extension is

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auto-currency-switcher-1.html

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the currency import through back end.
System->Configuration->Currency setup->Scheduled Import Settings
Set import as per your requirement and the price will be updated daily.